# Percentage bar goes up as button is pressed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[the code so far](http://liveweave.com/FUypwi)

Now if you press a button, no matter which one, a div and a percentage will be shown. I've got that going for me, but if one div is toggled, and another one is pressed, the 66% div should be toggled and so on if two divs are shown and the third is toggled the 100% div should show up. 
Basicly if you click a button, a div and a percentage div is revealed if you click aonther the percentage bar goes up. How do I do this? if two divs are toggled and if you press the button two diffrent divs are shown?

JS

```
function showhide()
{
    var div = document.getElementById("lol");
    var id3 = document.getElementById("3");
    var id5 = document.getElementById("5");

    if (div.style.display !== "none") 
    { 

        div.style.display = "none";
        id3.style.display = "none";
    }
    else {
        div.style.display = "block";
    }

}

function showhide2()
{
    var div2 = document.getElementById("lol2");

    if (div2.style.display !== "none") {
        div2.style.display = "none";
    }
    else {
        div2.style.display = "block";
    }
}

function showhide3()
{
    var div3 = document.getElementById("lol3");

    if (div3.style.display !== "none") {
        div3.style.display = "none";
    }
    else {
        div3.style.display = "block";
    }
}
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>HTML5, CSS3 and JavaScript demo</title>
</head>
<body>
<!-- Start your code here -->
<div id="lol"><p>div1</p></div>
<div id="lol2"><p>div2</p></div>
  <div id="lol3"><p>div3</p></div>
<button id="button" onclick="showhide()">div1</button>  
  <button id="button" onclick="showhide2()">div2</button>   

  <button id="button" onclick="showhide3()">div3</button>   
  <div id = "3"><p>33%</p></div>
  <div id = "5"><p>66%</p></div>
  <div id = "5"><p>100%</p></div>
<!-- End your code here -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Relevant code HAS to be provided in question itself

Comment: Please post the code in your question, not a link.

Comment: Can you explain a simple example.

Comment: 3 buttons with duplicate Id?

Comment: `id` of `div` with `<p>66%</p>` and `<p>100%</p>` also repeated.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure what you mean but I think it might be something like this?

http://liveweave.com/PcZ7vL

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>HTML5, CSS3 and JavaScript demo</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="lol1"><p>div1</p></div>
  <div id="lol2"><p>div2</p></div>
  <div id="lol3"><p>div3</p></div>
  <button id="button" onclick="showhide()">div1</button>  
  <button id="button" onclick="showhide2()">div2</button>   
  <button id="button" onclick="showhide3()">div3</button>   
  <div id = "3"><p>33%</p></div>
  <div id = "5"><p>66%</p></div>
  <div id = "7"><p>100%</p></div>
</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript:

```
var one = 0
var two = 0
var three = 0
var id3 = document.getElementById("3");
var id5 = document.getElementById("5");
var id7 = document.getElementById("7");
var div1 = document.getElementById("lol1");
var div2 = document.getElementById("lol2");
var div3 = document.getElementById("lol3");
id3.style.display = "none";
id5.style.display = "none";
id7.style.display = "none";
div1.style.display = "none";
div2.style.display = "none";
div3.style.display = "none";

    function showhide()
{
    if (div1.style.display !== "none") 
    { 
        div1.style.display = "none";
        one = 0
    }
    else {
        div1.style.display = "block";
        one = 1
    }
    showper();
}

function showhide2()
{
    if (div2.style.display !== "none") {
        div2.style.display = "none";
        two = 0
    }
    else {
        div2.style.display = "block";
        two = 1
    }
    showper()
}

function showhide3()
{
    if (div3.style.display !== "none") {
        div3.style.display = "none";
        three = 0
    }
    else {
        div3.style.display = "block";
        three = 1
    }
    showper()
}

function showper()
{
    var sum = one + two + three

    id3.style.display = "none";
    id5.style.display = "none";
    id7.style.display = "none";

    if (sum == 1) {
        id3.style.display = "block";
    } else if (sum == 2) {
        id5.style.display = "block";
    } else if (sum == 3) {
        id7.style.display = "block";
    }
    else {
        id3.style.display = "none";
        id5.style.display = "none";
        id7.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

EDIT:
A slightly neater way to do it would be this: http://liveweave.com/YAHn55.

Also, you should take a look at jQuery, makes things like this much simpler.

EDIT:
[see example](http://liveweave.com/82KHtz)